# Relative path for dynamic web project using jax-rs

Tags: java, jax-rs

I want to use app_config file in my code and want to load it when starting the project in server.

```
package test.controller;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.mysql.cj.core.util.StringUtils;

import test.config.AppConfig;
import test.connection.jdbc.JDBCConnection;

@ApplicationPath("webapp")
public class RestApplication extends Application{

    public static final String CONFIG_FILE = "C:\\Users\\chakrabo\\eclipse-workspace\\HelloWorld\\config\\src\\main\\resources\\app-config.xml";
    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
    public static AppConfig appConfig = getConfig();
    public static Connection con = JDBCConnection.getConnection(appConfig.getDbUrl(), 
            appConfig.getUsername(), appConfig.getPassword());

    private static AppConfig getConfig() {
        try {
            AppConfig config = objectMapper.readValue(
            StringUtils.toString(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(CONFIG_FILE))), AppConfig.class);
            return config;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("RestApplication : getConfig " +e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

With actual path i am able to read this app-config file. but i dont know how to read it based on relative path.

[image]

Context should be HelloWorld(project name) but it does not work. even if i put this config folder inside webcontent and WEB-INF still it says file not found exception.

can anyone help me.

Comment: It has to be in the WebContent folder to be,detected,by JAX-RS

Answer (score 1):

To get the path to a file, try using the ServletContext.

Make a field (global instance variable) in the Application as such:

```
@Context
ServletContext servletContext;
```

Then use

```
String path = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/app-config.xml");
```

This makes use of JAX-RS's built-in Dependency Injection mechanism.

You need the Servlet API as such

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This requires it to be in the WebContent folder (WEB-INF specifically)

Comment: Thanks . i have added my config file in webcontent. now i am not able to import ServletContext  in my RestApplication class. 
    org.glassfish.jersey.core
    jersey-client
    version : 2.22.1


    org.glassfish.jersey.containers    jersey-container-servlet
    version: 2.22.1
These are my maven dependencies. Is there any other jar i need to add

Comment: @subro Yes, the Servlet API. I have updated the answer with the correct Dependency

Comment: @subro what error are you getting. Is it at compile time, or runtime

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
RestApplication.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("app-config.xml")));
```

With this you can load files from `src/main/resources` folder